# GMap Api geocoder.getLatLng (address) function , Doesn't work good when call it within loop

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying this recursion function to find LatLng of 2088 diffrent addresses and replay me with only about 180 results . although all addresses are valid on google maps website .

```
function test(i)
         {
            if(i >= jsArray.length){return;}
               var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder(); 
             geocoder.getLatLng(jsArray[i], function (current) { 
                     return function(point) { 
                                     if (!point) {

                                    data.push("null");
                                    //nulls.push(myindex);
                                  } else {

                                    data.push(point);

                                    //alert("done");
                                  }

                                test(i+1,jsArray);
                            } 

                        }(i));


                 } 


                test(0);
```

---

i have developed this recursive function but it's need about 30 mins till get good results ,

```
 function test2(i)
             {
                 geocoder.getLocations(jsArray[i], function (current) { 
                 return function(response) { 
                                 if (!response || response.Status.code != 200) {
                                //alert(address + " not found");
                                 //test(i,jsArray);
                                // data.push("null");
                                //nulls.push(myindex);
                                test2(i);

                              } else {
                                 var len = response.Placemark[0];

                                    point2 = new GLatLng(
                                      len.Point.coordinates[1],
                                      len.Point.coordinates[0]
                                    );  
                                data[i] = point2;
                              }
                        }
                        }(i));
             } 



            for(i =0 ; i<=jsArray.length; i++)
            {
                if(i==jsArray.length){
                      alert(data.length);
                    ///  $("#maintable").show(100) ;                         
                    ///  $("#loading").hide(100) ;

                }else{
                    test2(i);
                }

            }
```

i still need   expert one to help me :) :D

Comment: You're using API v2, which is deprecated and will probably stop working entirely after May 19, 2013.  Strongly suggest you rewrite it completely for API v3.

Answer (score 1):

The geocoder is asynchronous (which makes using it in loops problematic) and subject to a quota and rate limits.  It is not intended for displaying lots of known addresses on a map, it is intended for user entered data.

You really should geocode your points off line, save the resulting coordinates and use those coordinates to display markers on your map.

If you are using it in a loop, you shouldn't use the getLatLng method, you should use the [getLocations method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference#GClientGeocoder.getLocations), which contains a [status code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference#GGeoStatusCode) that will let you know why it is failing (G_GEO_TOO_MANY_QUERIES
= 620, would mean you could throttle your requests and potentially get a useful result)

Comment: thanx for ur replay : i should loop on the function getLocations about 2087 time so some times its return latlng correct and other times return null :D:D getLocations or geocode :D no diffrence :D

Comment: You are abusing the service if you are not throttling the rate at which you are requesting the results.  You need to check the status on the getLocations (there is no status availble on the getLatLng.

Answer (score 0):

// jsArray is array of  addresses . the length of this array is 2087 element, all addresses got from google maps .

```
function MYFunction(i)
         {
             geocoder.getLocations(jsArray[i], function (current) { 
             return function(response) { 
                             if (!response || response.Status.code != 200) {

                              test2(i); // recursive calling 

                          } else {
                             var len = response.Placemark[0];

                                point2 = new GLatLng(
                                  len.Point.coordinates[1],
                                  len.Point.coordinates[0]
                                );  
                            data[i] = point2;
                          }
                    }
                    }(i));
         }  /// end of y Function
```

//// loop for each address and pass it to MyFunction function  and start recursive function .

```
        for(i =0 ; i<=jsArray.length; i++)
        {
                 MYFunction(i);

        }
```